# Get parameter in PDO Query is dangerous or not?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm using 5 get search parameters for my pdo queries. So, I'm wondering is that dangerous or not?

**For example:**

```
$s_username = "";

   if(isset($_GET["username"])){
      $s_username = " AND ac_username LIKE %".$_GET["username"]."% ";
   }

      $appUsers = $db->query("SELECT ac_user FROM accounts WHERE ac_app = '{$appFind["id"]}' '{$s_username}' ")->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

(I know, there is an example and I can use other techniques but it is only a simple example. So, I'm using more search term or parameter.)

If, it's really dangerous, can you please suggest me some alternatives?

Comment: Yes, it's definitely dangerous. You are wide open to [**SQL injection**](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection). Use prepared statements instead of direct concatenation.

Comment: Thanks! But I can't use because I'm adding " AND -columnname- LIKE .." text.  Is there any other way?

Comment: Yes, you can. Just add the placeholders to your variables before passing them into the prepared statement. In other words, have a statement like `... WHERE ... LIKE ? ...`, and pass a value like `'%' . $x . '%'` instead of just `$x`.

Comment: I'm sorry really but I didn't understood it. Can you write a sample with multiple WHERE parameter while using $_GET's parameter as second WHERE query just like my example? :)

Comment: You're going to have to do something like `$s_username = " AND ac_username LIKE ?";`, then use a prepared statement instead of a direct query. When you pass a parameter to the statement handler, instead of passing it `$_GET["username"]`, pass it `'%' . $_GET["username"] . '%'`. It's hard to provide much more detail than that without knowing what `$db` is (is it an instance of the PDO class, or a wrapper of some sort?), but that ought to be enough to help you solve the problem.

Comment: Ah okay! I did it with your previous answer: ```$appUsers = $db->prepare("SELECT ac_user FROM accounts WHERE ac_app = '{$appFind["id"]}' AND ac_username LIKE ?");
// second line //
        $appUsers->execute(array("%$s_username%"));``` .. Is it okay now Sir? If it is dangerous too, I will try an another way with your last comment.

Comment: Yes, that would work. Just be sure `$appFind["id"]` can't contain any user input. As a rule, you want to use prepared statements and placeholders for *all* variable values, whenever possible. When it's not possible (such as a table name, which can't be a parameter), use whitelisted values.

Comment: Okay, I understood :) Thank you so much! :)